# A function that execute once when scrollY is higher than 100vh

Tags: javascript

I want call my function once when the statement if (scrollY > 100vh), but on every scroll when I get more than 100vh is calling func. I understand the reason why is that, but don't know how to fix that.

Perhaps it is simple but I can't do that.

I want a simple animation on scrolling.

code :

```
import anime from 'animejs';

var txt = document.querySelector('.textanimation');
txt.innerHTML = txt.textContent.replace(
     /\S/g,
     "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"
);

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
     const vh = window.innerHeight;
     const scrolled = window.scrollTop;
     if (scrolled > vh) {
          const scrollTextAnimation = anime.timeline();
          scrollTextAnimation
               .add({
                    targets: '.textanimation .letter',
                    translateY: [-100, 0],
                    easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                    duration: 1400,
                    delay: (el, i) => 30 * i
               })
               .add({
                    targets: '.textanimation',
                    duration: 1000,
                    easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                    delay: 1000
               });
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

just add once option to the event listener to execute it one time.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
     const vh = window.innerHeight;
     const scrolled = window.scrollTop;
     if (scrolled > vh) {
          const scrollTextAnimation = anime.timeline();
          scrollTextAnimation
               .add({
                    targets: '.textanimation .letter',
                    translateY: [-100, 0],
                    easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                    duration: 1400,
                    delay: (el, i) => 30 * i
               })
               .add({
                    targets: '.textanimation',
                    duration: 1000,
                    easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                    delay: 1000
               });
     }
}, {once: true});
```

Comment: That's what I thought at first as well, but then it won't execute again when it goes back below the threshold.  I think the OP wants it to execute again.

Comment: After it executes once the event listener is removed so if the if statement is false on that first event then the logic inside the if statement won't ever run.

Answer (score 1):

I just added a bool that change the statement to false when I make a scrollY more than innerHeight/2. "Once" option in addEventListener was not working, don't know why. Is there a better solution how to fix that?
The code below is working:

```
let myBool = true;
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
     if (window.scrollY > window.innerHeight / 2 && myBool) {
          anime.timeline()
               .add({
                    targets: '.textanimation .letter',
                    translateY: [-100, 0],
                    easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                    duration: 1400,
                    delay: (el, i) => 30 * i
               })
               .add({
                    targets: '.textanimation',
                    duration: 1000,
                    easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                    delay: 1000
               });

          myBool = false;
     }
});
```

Comment: Ah, so you did only want it to fire once and then never again!  You can also remove the event listener.

Comment: Removing the event listener is what the `once` option does.  Just put your logic into a separate function and then call `window.removeEventListener('scroll', <name of your function>)` at the end of your if statement.

Comment: Thank you a lot @j3py, yes I wanted to execute it only once.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the event listener after your logic executes in order to stop it from ever firing again.  You can do this in two ways:

1) Use the `once` option as defined in the parameters for `addEventListener` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).  This option automatically removes the event listener after the event happens once.  The OP has already stated this isn't working for them (possibly because the scroll needs to reach a certain height before the logic works so it is being removed too early).

2) Call `removeEventListener` after the logic executes:

```
import anime from 'animejs';

var txt = document.querySelector('.textanimation');
txt.innerHTML = txt.textContent.replace(
     /\S/g,
     "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"
);

var animateOnce = function() {
    const vh = window.innerHeight;
     const scrolled = window.scrollTop;
     if (scrolled > vh) {
          const scrollTextAnimation = anime.timeline();
          scrollTextAnimation
               .add({
                    targets: '.textanimation .letter',
                    translateY: [-100, 0],
                    easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                    duration: 1400,
                    delay: (el, i) => 30 * i
               })
               .add({
                    targets: '.textanimation',
                    duration: 1000,
                    easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                    delay: 1000
               });
         // remove the event listener after the animation happens on the first time
         window.removeEventListener('scroll', animateOnce);
     }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', animateOnce);
```

3) Here are a couple of other solutions in [a post on sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-one-time-events-javascript/).

Comment: It's not working. When we got a value of ScrollTop higher than innerHeight (vh) I want just to add an animation once, but when I scroll and scroll function is executing all the time I scroll.

Comment: The function will execute on all scrolling events.  That's why I suggested you track the last known value of the height you are checking for and add an additional check in the if statement for that last known value.  If you provide more detail maybe I can help more.  I will edit my answer to what I think you are saying.

Comment: In light of new information I have edited my answer.